# iMac mid-2010 memory upgrade

Tags: mac, upgrade, memory

I want to upgrade memory in my mid-2010 21.5" iMac. I've found that Kingston 2GB module with product ID KVR1333D3S9 is available at my local store, and want to buy it.

iMac mid 2010 memory specification says...

```
You can use any Small-Outline dual inline memory
modules (SO-DIMMS) that meet all of these criteria:

PC3-10600, Unbuffered, Nonparity, 204-pin, 1333 MHz, DDR3 SDRAM

DIMMs with any of the following features do not work in the iMac (Mid 2010):

Registers or buffers, PLLs, ECC, Parity, EDO RAM
```

I've also found [specification for this memory module](http://www.valueram.com/datasheets/KVR1333D3S9_2G.pdf), but it uses too much techno-speak and I'm still not sure if they go together. Basic parameters seems ok though. My question is ... is this the right memory module for new iMac?

Comment: iMac mid 2010 mem specs is at http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4255

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is:

Print out the page [linked](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4255) in the comment, take the printout to the store and tell them you want memory modules matching those specifications. No need to decipher some hard to understand memory spec from a pdf yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why this didn't occur to me ;-) I asked at my apple premium reseller and sure they have memory modules that fit into new imac at similar price (even bit cheaper).

Comment: @random - I to sometimes forget that there are people out there that are paid to help me. I don't have to do things myself *all* the time.

Answer (score 1):

The Kingston KVR1333D3S9/2G memory matches the specs supplied in your question, it should work fine.